# Возвращаемое значение функций

Tags: c++, функции

Не могли бы вы подсказать, можно ли задать функции возвращаемое значение по-умолчанию еще при ее объявлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Простая реализация Expected](https://www.google.com/amp/s/bell0bytes.eu/expected/amp/). Если используется C++17, то вполне возможно сделать что-то типа такого: `Expected<15> cacl(auto first, auto second);`, используя `auto in template parameters`.

Answer (score 4):

Нет. В С++ нет такой концепции, как "возвращаемое значение по умолчанию" для функции. За исключением функции `main`, возврат значения из функции в С++ всегда делается *явно*.

Comment: А из `main` через что?

Comment: @Pavel Gridin: `main` ведет себя как `return 0`, если вы сами явно не сделали никакого `return`.

Comment: да, вернёт она мусор как миленькая без return

Comment: @Pavel Gridin: Еще раз: в языках С и С++ функция `main` гарантированно ведет себя как `return 0`, если управление достигает последней закрывающей `}`. Это требуется спецификациями этих языков.

Answer (score 0):

А смысл его задавать?

Ты никак не можешь прервать выполнение функции кроме оператора return. А в нём вполне можно указать значение. Ну а если выполнение функции не прерывается преждевременным return'ом, то оно завершается на её последней фигурной скобке, перед которой и следует разместить return с этим дефаултным значением.

```
int f(/* args */)
{
  /* any code */

  return 42; // default value
}
```

Comment: Ну, согласно формулировке вопроса, все суть по-видимому состоит в том, чтобы как-то задавать это возвращаемое значение по умолчанию именно *в точке объявления* функции, а не в ее определении.

Comment: @AnT, ну я могу задефайнить обёртку, которая будет сама иметь аргумент в начале, а разворачивать его в return в конце. Только это бред какой-то))